# How do I open a hidden sheet with hyperlink in google sheets?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm creating a risk assessment worksheet which begins to have a lot of sheets. I would like to hide most of them and get access to them thru hyperlinks in the main sheet.
This, however, is not possible since as soon I hide the sheets I want hidden, the hyperlink cannot open them.
Is there a script I can use for the hyperlink or can I make a "button" with a script to solve this?
I would also like to produce a similar link or button on the target page to get it hidden when returning to the main page.

I've searched for an answer on the web but have only found answers for how to do it in Excel.

Comment: Write a sidebar for this. Your sidebar would be able to invoke a server-side function with the name of the sheet to unhide, etc. This sort of navigation functionality probably already exists in an add-on. It's also complex enough that asking or expecting anyone to do it here for free is inappropriate. Feel free to ask specific questions about your implementation if you choose to create it yourself and encounter difficulties you need help surmounting.

Comment: I do not expect to get it done for me, but I do expect to be pointed in the right direction since I do not know zip about Google sheet. You say "Write a sidebar", sure what is that? That's where I am so pls, all I ask for is some instruments to educate myself.

Comment: "Google apps script sidebar" is a great internet search. Probably you should start with that.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
function showOneSheet(name) {
  var name=name || 'Sheet1';//for debugging
  if(name) {
    var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
    var sh=ss.getSheetByName(name);
    if(sh.isSheetHidden()) {
      sh.showSheet();
    }
    var shts=ss.getSheets();
    for(var i=0;i<shts.length;i++) {
      if(shts[i].getName()!=name) {
        shts[i].hideSheet();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

If you wish to call it from a sidebar or a dialog then you can use [google.script.run](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run).  This will show just one sheet at a time.

[Class Sheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet)

Comment: I really appreciate it Cooper but I haven't tried it yet since I don't know how to implement it. How do I trigger the script? My intention initially was to create a hyperlink (and place this in a cell) to the hidden sheet in order to get redirected to that sheet. I'll give it some tries to figure it out. I'll let you know how it works out.